# how to fetch only the new documents from firebase?

Tags: android, kotlin, repository, repository-pattern

I have an app for books , in First time for a new user the app fetch data from sever contains list of all books but every week I will add new list of book , how I will update my sqlliteDB  with the new books only and keep old the same

Its like a strategy for repository , How we do that

Answer (score 1):

Check for unique id of each record in sqliteDB and if same record found then skip it otherwise insert new record with unique id of firebase record.